# position/offset of div returning as 0

Tags: javascript, css, position, offset

Here is my css for my circle

```
#balloon-circle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgb(255,100,100);
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    top:5px;
}
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var bc = document.getElementById("balloon-circle");
var bctop = bc.offsetTop;
console.log(bctop);
```

I've also tried:

```
var bc = $("#balloon-circle");
var position = bc.position();
console.log(position.top);
```

However, they both return 0 for the top position value.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your position to "relative" or "absolute" before you can use top.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

```
#balloon-circle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgb(255,100,100);
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
}
```

Comment: `fixed` can work too ;) (simply any non-static position)